# Linux Mounting Problem

Tags: linux, mount, clonezilla

I have an Iomega Network Attached Storage device on my Windows network. I am trying to use a clonezilla live USB flash drive to backup my netbook to my Iomega Network Attached Storage device. The clonezilla USB flash drive runs linux. I'm having trouble getting the Network Attached Storage unit to mount using the following command:

> mount -t cifs -o username="myUsername" //192.168.1.100/backup /home/partimg

The response from linux is:

> [134.730738] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount
>   failed w/return code = -6
>   retrying with upper case share name
>   [134.788461] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount
>   failed w/return code = -6
>  mount
>   error(6): No such device or address
>   Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual
>   page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

I also tried adding the following to my username:

> username="myUsername,domain=workgroup"

but that did not change the error. I am able to ping the network attached storage unit from linux on my netbook. I also booted from a Slax Live USB Flash Drive and Slax auto-mounted my network attached storage unit via Samba. Unfortunately, I don't believe that I can run clonezilla from inside the Slax installation.

Does anyone have any insight about what is wrong with my mount statement? Or is there something peculiar about Iomega drives which makes this impossible?

Answer (score 2):

I have a few suggestions:

- [code -6 means the server isn't a valid share](http://lists.samba.org/archive/linux-cifs-client/2007-August/002169.html). Check that it works from a window box.
- follow the synopsis in `man mount.cifs`, the signature of the command is `mount.cifs {service} {mount-point} [-o options]` -- the `-o` comes after the `-t` and `mount-point` (`-o` normally goes at the end of mount commands.
- add the `--verbose` flag prior to the *-o stuff*

`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should add quotes, it should be:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=server_user,password=secret //192.168.1.100/share /path_to/mount
```